# iPhone how to programmatically estimate Google search engine traffic for a set of keywords?

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, search-engine, traffic

I got a set of keywords that the user can type:
keyword1,
keyword2,
keyword3,
...
Up to 10 keywords

I'm looking for a way to estimate Google search engine traffic for these keywords. I would love to make a single GET request with all these keywords at once or one by one and display the search engine volume to the user.

**Is there a web API from google that I can use to query keyword search engine volume?**

If there's no such API, I would not mind opening some kind of web-based search engine tool and pass keywords to it, so the user can view the results in a  webView. Is this possible?

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [traffic estimator](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/TrafficEstimatorService) service with the Adwords API.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a little tool for that, the tool is so small that they don't really have an api for it! But you could make it look integrated by getting the text from a webview then displaying it in a TextView.

LINK:http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends